# How to configure gcp-storage trigger for keda scaler

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, keda

I'm trying to configure a Keda Scaler with **gcp-storage** as trigger, using workload identity as authentication. I have verified my service account has both Storage Admin & Storage Object Admin Roles in my IAM roles. Here is the YAML File with the **TriggerAuthentication** and **ScaledJob**

I'm maintaining the values file to fetch the service account details and other key values.

*TriggerAuthentication*

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-gcp-credentials
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: gcp
```

*ScaledJob*

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  name: sample-scaled-job
  namespace: default
  labels:
      {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: sample-scaled-job
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: sample-scaled-job
      spec:
        imagePullSecrets: {{ .Values.deployment.imagePullSecrets | toYaml | nindent 8 }}
        serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.serviceaccount.name }}
        containers:
          - name: sample-job-container
            image: nginx
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command: ["echo","Mukesh"]
  pollingInterval:  5                    # Optional. Default: 5 seconds
  minReplicaCount:  0                   # Optional. Default: 0
  maxReplicaCount:  2                    # Optional. Default: 100
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  rollout:
    strategy: gradual
    propagationPolicy: foreground
  triggers:
  - type: gcp-storage
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-auth-gcp-credentials
    metadata:
      bucketName: "ccon-ap-core-pilot-us-east4-gcs"
      targetObjectCount: "5"
      blobPrefix: "inputs/"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 Type     Reason              Age                    From           Message                                                                                          │
│   ----     ------              ----                   ----           -------                                                                                          │
│   Normal   KEDAScalersStarted  38m                    scale-handler  Started scalers watch                                                                            │
│   Warning  KEDAScalerFailed    38m                    scale-handler  context canceled                                                                                 │
│   Warning  KEDAScalerFailed    38m                    scale-handler  scaler with id 0 not found, len = 0, cache has been probably already invalidated                 │
│   Normal   ScaledJobReady      36m (x3 over 38m)      keda-operator  ScaledJob is ready for scaling                                                                   │
│   Warning  KEDAScalerFailed    3m44s (x420 over 38m)  scale-handler  googleapi: Error 403: Caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Stora │
│ ge bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist)., forbidden
```